# Add Asterisk extensions remotely

Tags: android, asterisk, sip

I have an asterisk server installed, I just wonder if I can add some extensions remotely with an Android app, for example a person who installed my app & register for an account the app will add a new extension in /etc/asterisk/sip.conf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, certainly. The best way to do this is to use Realtime configuration for your extensions, and point them to a database. This way your app can use a web API (such as a PHP script) to update the database, and asterisk will see the extension immediately.

Official docs [here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Realtime+Database+Configuration).

Unofficial page with some good (though potentially outdated) info [here](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime+Extensions).

- Point of interest: the Caveat section mentions extension patterns and their very negative effects for realtime configs.